# How to code an interface which sends an email or fax

Tags: java

I have to code an interface I_Contactable with the method public void contactMerchant (String purpose, String text) in which i can send an email to a merchant. But if the merchant hasn't got an emailadresse, the message should go through by faxnumber.

There will be a 'merchant' class with all required attributes like emailadress and faxnumber in which the interface should be implemented.

It is just a simulation of sending an email which means the email should just appear in the console as an output.

I'm just in the very beginning of my studies so the code should be in a basic way.

I will appreciate every answers.

Comment: You should really learn that an interface is. You design an interface, but the functions and how it works is described by an implementing class, not the interface itself.

Comment: "the code should be in a basic way". That is true. At the same time, there is an expectation that you will have attempted to solve the problem yourself before posting on Stack Overflow. Please do so, and show the attempt as well as a description of how it turned out in your question. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service after all.

Comment: thans for your feedback! I'm new in this business and i have to learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want your `IContactable` interface to be generic and reusable, you should have have just a simple `void contact(String purpose, String text)` method (note there is no "merchant" in the name of the method).

Then in the class *implementing* the interface, let's call it `MerchantContactService` you can have something in the likes of:

```
@Override
void contact(String purpose, String text) {
  if (this.merchant.hasEmailAddress()) {
    sendEmail(purpose, text, this.merchant.getEmail());
  } else {
    sendFax(purpose, text, this.merchant.getFaxNumber();
  }
}
```

Assuming you have a `merchant` field in the `MerchantContactService` class, and the merchant has the necessary methods and getters. Now this class is a *concrete implementation* of the interface and it can be merchant specific.

EDIT: The code behind `sendEmail()` and `sendFax()` is up to you, since this wasn't a part of your question.

Comment: looks quite simple, thank you!

Comment: @Faint Feel free to accept it, if it works for you